# Can byte set 01 as value

Tags: java

Here is a small program

```
public class example {  
    private byte b1;
    public byte getB1() {
        return b1;
    }
    public void setB1(byte b1) {
        this.b1 = b1;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    final byte a = 01;  
    example e =  new example();
    e.setB1(a);
    System.out.println(e.getB1());
    }
}
```

This program return value as 1 not 01, however, I am expecting it to be 01 (which has been set)
How to get 01 output from byte, if 01 has been set.

Comment: you need to change the print statement. like below
System.out.print("%02d%",e.getB1());

Comment: it is `octal` representation in java

Comment: A byte is a number -- it contains no formatting information.  So 1 == 0x01 == 001 (octal) == 0b00000001.

Answer (score 15):

You need to differentiate between a *text* representation and an inherent value.

I'm 37 years old. I'm also 0x25 years old, and 045 years old (octal) - they're the same number, in different representations. The number itself has no concepts of a representation.

If you want to convert a byte to a string in a particular way, you should do that as part of formatting - it's *not* part of the data associated with a byte. The *value* is the same however you initialize it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun It was the same as the ESC char, now you are just the FS ;)

Comment: @Jon, in case if I want to store byte value as 01, for example in DB2 database if the field is smallint, and I want to store 01 not 1 then how to set smallint value as 01 (byte)

Comment: @Rakesh: You can't. They're fundamentally the same value. If you care about the *textual representation* of data, you should be storing a string instead.

Answer (score 7):

`01 == 1 == 001 == 00000001`, they are all the same value.  If you want change the way it is printed, you need to change the print statement.

```
System.out.printf("%02d%", e.getB1()); // print a leading zero.
```

Comment: Thanks it will work for display. But in case if 01 needs to be store in DB (in DB2 against smallint) then how to set 01 ?

Comment: @Rakesh A smallint is like a short in Java, it doesn't have a leading 0.  The leading 0 is only for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

try  below, Just an another way

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class example {   
    private byte b1;
    public byte getB1() {
        return b1;
    }
    public void setB1(byte b1) {
        this.b1 = b1;
    }
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    final byte a = 1;  
    example e =  new example();
    e.setB1(a);
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("00");
    System.out.println( df.format(e.getB1()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try below,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    final byte a = 01;  
    example e =  new example();
    e.setB1(a);

    System.out.println(String.format("0%d", e.getB1()));
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`a` and `b1`, and the return value of `getB1`, are numbers, and `01` and `1` are the same number, namely one. If you want the zero to be preserved, you could change them into strings, but then you cannot do calculations with them anymore.